# Using char and int together

Tags: c, text, char, int

I'm trying to use char for identifying the outcome of the text.

For example, i have a file.txt which contains letters like: iiixxiix

I would like to replace the i's with numbers: 123xx67x and so on.

What should I be doing, to get such outcome? I can't seem to use int to replace a char ( srt[i] = c; ) and I have no idea how to move foward from the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   char str[60];
   int i;
   int c = 1;

   /* opening file for reading */
   fp = fopen("file.txt" , "r");
   if(fp == NULL)
   {
      perror("Error opening file");
      return(-1);
   }
   if( fgets (str, 22, fp)!=NULL )
   {
     for (i = 0; i < 22; i++)
     {
         if (str[i] == 'i')
         {
             str[i] = '0';
         }
        printf("%c", str[i]);
     }
   }
   fclose(fp);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Replacing `str[i] = '0';` with `str[i] = '1' + i;` would be a start. But this won't work if i>9. Also, the jump from `123` to `78` in your question needs an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But i need numbers higher than 9.

Comment: And sorry, i edited the question, i meant 123 to 67. The two X are also counted.

Answer (score 0):

The C specification requires that all digit characters are encoded contiguously. And if you look at the common and mostly used [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) you will see that the digits are encoded from `48` to `57`.

That means it's very easy to use the integer index `i` (modulo `10`) and add `'0'` to get the characters.

Simple example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 22; ++i)
{
    printf("Index %d to character '%c'\n", i, (char) (i % 10 + '0'));
}
```

Comment: Your example code seems not working, I only get empty field or symbols for digit.

Comment: @KarlJoonasVolke Ah yes, I had the wrong modulo. Better use normal integers and just add `'0'`. Will update answer.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I need the numbers to go higher than 9. After 9, the char starts showing only the last number. I guess i cant do it with char.

Comment: @KarlJoonasVolke No in that case you need strings. `sprintf` comes to mind.